# How to get Bacteria to attach to an Object?

Tags: bacteriology

I have cultured Cyanobacteria (in a media) in a beaker. I want that bacteria to attach to a cloth (e.g. Carbon). My current method is using a syringe to slowly push the bacteria to one side of a cylindric tube and exist through the other end. The cloth is placed stationary inside that tube throughout the process.

Is there a way to get more bacteria to attach to the cloth? (e.g.maybe adding something to the cloth)

Comment: Why do you want them attached to the cloth?

Comment: I am doing a study to see how long can I help the bacteria live in the cloth and I want to store as much bacteria as I can.

Comment: I wonder if you could try this [membrane filter technique](https://microbeonline.com/membrane-filter-technique/), but replace the membrane with a fabric of your choosing.

Comment: You might also be interested in these [CDC Biofilm reactors](https://biofilms.biz/products/biofilm-reactors/cdc-biofilm-reactor/), if your cyanobacteria are biofilm formers.

Comment: Thank you, I will read about them and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking in terms of making them attach to your cloth, but they want to be attached - there are more nutrients and it is safer.  Make sure they have enough light, but not too much, and their nutrients.  They may be attaching and growing, but just not as fast as you expect.

It is also possible that your strain of Cyanobacteria has lost the ability to attach.  If it has been maintained in liquid culture for many generations, any bacteria attached to the wall of the container were selected against.